# Connect and r - - - - e

Tags: knowledge, visual

**What is drawn below? Give me the answer (5, 7, 7) and explain your reasoning.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> **SEVEN SEGMENT DISPLAY**

Reason being:

> Convert A-Z to two digits numbers from 01-26.
>
> Then, convert these numbers to their seven segment display format. Perform a XOR operation between the first digit and the second digit for each of the seven segments to obtain the encoded version of that letter. We will get the encoding as shown below:
>
> [image: Encoding]

> Note that the encoding is not one to one. For example, L (12) and U (21) will have the same representation in their encoded forms.
>
> However, the ambiguity is easily resolved when trying to come up with a phrase that makes sense.
>
> Seven segment display, of course, makes sense as the final answer as it is part of the mechanism used in the encoding.

Comment: Yup, that's the answer. Nice job!